# How to register subdomain at https://id.craftcms.com/licenses/cms

Tags: license

We use a subdomain for our headless Craft CMS install that looks like api.example.org.  When I try to enter that as the "Domain Name" on the Craft ID site, the "Domain Name" form field doesn't allow for a subdomain.  I.e. if I enter api.example.org, and hit save, it reads example.org.  And so, in the CMS dashboard I am getting the `The license located at config/license.key belongs to example.org` warning.  Is there some other way I should indicate the subdomain for this craft license?  Do I need to move the CMS to its own domain?

Answer (score 1):

Craft licenses doesn’t care about subdomains - your license will be registered to the `example.com` subdomain, and will technically be valid for any subdomain for that domain. Read more about Craft license enforcement here: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/more-information-than-you-require-about-craft-license-keys#domains

**If you’re getting that error when visiting the Craft control panel via `api.example.com`, something is wrong.** Things to try:

- Clear Craft’s data caches
- Double-check that the site is using the correct license, and that the license is in fact registered to the same top-level domain (ie `example.com`)

If you’re still unable to get rid of that error, I’d suggest getting in touch with Craft support.